# insert 1 row into another table and the update the original row. for multiple rows

Tags: sql, for-loop, cursor

I have a 2 tables, one is My production table (PROD) and the other is my journal table(JOUR) (JOUR has the same fields as PROD)

a recent bug in production is causing some Rows in prod to not be updated. wp what i have to do in SQL is the following.

1) select all the rows in Prod where Condition='A' and Type = ' '

2) copy The first row to JOUR

3) set Type for the first row to 'C'

4) repeat 3 and 4  for the rest of the rows that match the condition in 1

I am not allowed to just select PROD into JOUR and then update all the rows in PROD that meet the conditions.

I am fairly new to SQL, and have had a hard time doing this. in OOP i would just have used a for

Comment: Do you mean "update all the rows in JOUR (instead of PROD). Why can't you use a simple "insert into jour (condition,type) 
select condition, 'C' from prod where condition='A' and type=''"?

Comment: Which version of what SQL product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[Output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) should get you there. [Great tutorial for output clause](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/)